# Windows lost server connection while transferring files via Samba

Tags: windows, networking, router, samba, netgear

I have a Ubuntu 22.04.1 server with Samba installed to allow other PC in the local network to upload/download files, there are 2 Windows clients (Windows 10 & 11), and they both are ok to connect and upload/download files to the Ubuntu server (via file explorer), all 3 machines are connecting to the network via WiFi (Netgear router).

The problem is when trying to upload a large batch of files, the connection between the client and server will be disconnected, and the client will not be able to ping the server, only a lot of files or a large size of file will trigger this issue.

The server is then completely invisible to the client, but this won't affect the other clients in the same network (only the client who is transferring files will be affected)

The server will remain unreachable unless the client disconnects from the WiFi and reconnect to it

I am searching for a solution but cannot find the correct keywords. Also, I am having no idea how to start the investigation and checked the Netgear log, it is only showing the WiFi connect history

any help would be appreciated

---

Edit 1

tried `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and delayed the connection drop for a significant of time, however this command is not recommended and not solving the root

also tried `oplocks = no` and `fake oplocks = yes`, the connection is dropped for a couple of times, still testing

Comment: oplocks + fake oplocks + crontabs systemctl restart nmbd.service seems fixed for me, will leave this open for a more proper answer